# Problems with environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I ame using Linux Mint and I have to set some new environment variables.
I edited the file bash.bashrc in etc/ appending this line:

```
export NDK=/home/myname/Scrivania/android-ndk
```

but if i write on the shell the command $NDK i get this:

```
bash: home/myname/Scrivania/android-ndk: File o directory non esistente
```

why?

Comment: Have you sourced the file? `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Try to make sure that your file doesn't contain 0x13 or is not in DOS format.

What command makes use of the NDK variable? How is it used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$NDK` is not a command.  When you say `$NDK` at the shell prompt, then the OS tries to *execute* `/home/myname/Scrivania/android-ndk` which is probably not what you want.
2. Even if the directory `/home/myname/Scrivania/android-ndk` were to exist you would get the error you mentioned upon saying `$NDK`.  You probably wanted to say `cd $NDK` or such.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with setting those.  You are *retrieving* those incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

you get this error message exactly because you asked for it =)

```
sh#$NDK <enter>
```

keeping things simple such command tries to execute programs which stored inside NDK variable,
if it's what you tried to achieve then you should check that it's really exists.

if you want just to output value use:

```
sh#echo $NDK
```

Answer (score 0):

type `source .bashrc` 
in your terminal.

Comment: i get:  bash: .bashrc: File o directory non esistente

Comment: You are using `bash.bashrc`, so it must be `source bash.bashrc`.

Comment: the same: bash: bash.bashrc: File o directory non esistente